# how create a dependency tree using dot

Tags: tree, dependencies, dot

trying to create a dependency tree. although i have managed to get the boxes connect together, i have failed to make it looks like a tree in a more representable way.

```
digraph G{
m1[shape=box, color=grey, style=filled]
m2[shape=box, color=grey, style=filled]
m3[shape=box, color=grey, style=filled]
m4[shape=box, color=grey, style=filled]
m5[shape=box, color=grey, style=filled]
p1[shape=diamond,color=lightblue, style=filled]
p2[shape=diamond, color=lightblue, style=filled]
p3[shape=diamond, color=lightblue, style=filled]
p4[shape=diamond, color=lightblue, style=filled]
{rank=sink;x1;x2;x3;x4;}
{rank=source;y1;}
{rank=same;m3;p3;x11;x5;x6;x7;x8;}
node[shape=circle]
y1 -> x9
y1 -> m5
x10 -> m4
x10 -> p4
x9-> m3
x9-> p3
x6 ->m1
x6 ->p1
x5 ->m1
x5 ->p1
x8 -> m2
x8 -> p2
x7 -> m2
x7 -> p2
y1 -> x10
y1 -> x12  
x5 -> x1
x5 -> x2
x6 -> x1
x6 -> x2
x7 -> x3
x7 -> x4
x8 -> x3
x8 -> x4
x9 -> x6
x9 -> x5
x9 -> x11
x10 -> x8
x10 -> x7
}
```

i have failed to create something like 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your graph didn't look that bad to me. To get a little closer to your mockup picture, here's what could be done:

- Straighten the edges (`splines=false`)
- Increase the distance between the nodes (`ranksep=1`)
- Add **invisible edges** to ensure node order
- Personal preference: have edges origin from the same point (`edge[tailport=s]`)

Here's the modified graph:

```
digraph G{
splines=false;
ranksep=1;

node[shape=box, color=grey, style=filled];
m1;m2;m3;m4;m5;

node[shape=diamond,color=lightblue, style=filled]
p1;p2;p3;p4;

node[style=solid, color=black, shape=circle, width=0.6, height=0.6];
{
    rank=same;
    x9;x12;x10;m5;
}
{
    rank=same;
    edge[style=invis];
    p3->x11->x5->x6->m3;
    p4->x7->x8->m4;
}
{
    rank=same;
    edge[style=invis];
    p1->x1->x2->m1;
    p2->x3->x4->m2;
}

edge[tailport=s]; // also try adding: headport=n
y1 -> m5
y1 -> x9
y1 -> x12  
y1 -> x10
x10 -> m4
x10 -> p4
x9-> m3
x9-> p3
x6 ->m1
x6 ->p1
x5 ->m1
x5 ->p1
x8 -> m2
x8 -> p2
x7 -> m2
x7 -> p2
x5 -> x1
x5 -> x2
x6 -> x1
x6 -> x2
x7 -> x3
x7 -> x4
x8 -> x3
x8 -> x4
x9 -> x6
x9 -> x11
x9 -> x5
x10 -> x8
x10 -> x7
}
```

[image: graphivz output]

There's probably more that could be done, depending on what exactly you're after.

Comment: Thanks!! Seems the documentation is insufficient!! This will do!!